# Chef solo with Bazaar version control system

Tags: bazaar, chef-infra, bzr-svn

I created recipes in chef solo with following command

`bzr init`

`bzr branch sftp://username@ip/~/branch-name`

up to `bzr init` it will work but second command it **requires password for username** is there any method or option that i can use to send password with it or any way that does not require password

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the password to the URL:

```
bzr branch sftp://username:password@ip/~/branch-name
```

Comment: yes but this will also not working when giving the command as u put after  that it will ones again ask for password and as per my search, this feature is going to add in bzr 2.6b2 version and it will release in august2012 if any changes or any information i miss plz update me  thanks Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

You can append the login info to `~/.bazaar/authentication.conf` eg.:

```
# Identity on foo.net
[foo.net]
scheme=ftp
host=foo.net
user=joe
password=secret-pass
```

See this for more info: 
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/developers/authentication-ring.html

Comment: after this we have set BZR_SSH=paramiko then we can use bzr branch sftp://username:password@ip/~/branch-name